# ошибка в подключении драйвера базы данных

Tags: mysql, qt, ubuntu

Доброго времени суток. Хочу подключить драйвер для работы в qt с mysql. Пишу в .pro файле такие варианты:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers -libqsqlmysql.so
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers -libqsqlmysql
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers -llibqsqlmysql
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers -llibqsqlmysql.so
```

Вид ошибки: cannot find -llibqsqlmysql.so
Путь просто копирую, так что он указан верно. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А без .so пробовали? Обычно расширение указывать не надо

Comment: Да. Там же во втором и третьем варианте без .so

Comment: Ой, чот я просмотрел...